# Error During Configuration Wizard on SharePoint 2010

Tags: configuration-wizard, upgrade

I am able to successfully install SharePoint 2010 foundation on Windows Server 2008 SP2. However when I run the configuration wizard, it fails with the following error:

---

Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.RegisterAssembly(Dictionary`2 dictInitialType, Assembly asm, UInt32 nOrder)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.get_InitialTypeDictionary()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.GetDelegateTypes(Type tpObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.GetDelegates(Object o)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.GetUpgraders(Object o)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgradeFalse(Object o)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.set_NeedsUpgrade(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Update()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.RegisterDefaultDatabaseServices(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Provision(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, IdentityType identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword, SecureString masterPassphrase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword, SecureString masterPassphrase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

---

The assembly mentioned (Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c') does not appear in the GAC. I've tried reinstalling a dozen times with no luck.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused by "leftover" artifacts from a SharePoint 2010 Office Web Apps install. I was able to resolve this by:

- Uninstalling SharePoint 2010 Foundation
- Reinstalling Office Web Apps then uninstalling it. This time the uninstall completely removed the product.
- Reinstalling SharePoint 2010 Foundation

After taking the above steps I was able to successfully configure the farm.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently have MOSS, you want to upgrade to Server 2010, not Foundation which does not include Excel Services.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I don't think that's it though. MOSS is not present. The server previously had WSS 3.0 installed, but I uninstalled it before running the SharePoint 2010 Foundation install.

Answer (score 0):

Akil - I got the same exception, but it was a different assembly.  My problem was that I was trying to install it on a domain server that wasn't joined to the domain at the time.  I connected to the domain via VPN and it finished just fine (albeit it took a while).  For my second install, I connected via the local network and it was much faster.  I got the tip from this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx

If that doesn't do the trick, since you previously had WSS 3.0 on that same machine, I wonder if there may be a registry setting that didn't get cleaned up from the previous install.  SharePoint 2010 does a great job of installing all of the prereqs for you, so I'm guessing something didn't uninstall cleanly.

Comment: Hi Rob - Thanks for taking the time to respond. This server is actually on the network, so it is able to see the DC.

I think the idea of "leftover" artifacts is quite possibly close to being it. I noticed several registry entries leftover from an installation of Office Web Apps that don't look like they were cleaned up. I just did a reinstall of Web Apps so that I can attempt to uninstall it. I'll let you know how it goes...

Comment: BTW, I found these registry entries because in desperation I attempted to install SharePoint 2010 Server instead of Foundation, just to see what would happen. Server wouldn't even install, but it did give me this error message:

The install in progress conflicts with a previously installed Microsoft Office 2010 Server product"

Googling that lead me to this article, which showed me how to find the leftover entries: http://blogs.technet.com/b/chad/archive/2010/04/28/installing-sharepoint-2010-rtm-over-previous-versions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve that issue by installing the assembly of "Microsoft Chart Controls for the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5", one of the prerequisites to install SharePoint 2010. It can be downloaded from here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=122517